# View specific row based on username in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

Let's say I have a google site. On  the site is a gadget to a spreadsheet. I want the gadget to show one specific row from the spreadsheet based on the username of the person viewing the site. Is this possible with GAS?

Update:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("abcdefg123456789");
    var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
    var maxRows = first.getMaxRows();
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    //show all the rows
    first.showRows(1, maxRows);

    var data = first.getRange('A:A').getValues();

    //iterate over all rows
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][0] !== email) {
            first.hideRows(i + 1);
        }
        if (data[i][0] === "") {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with this code, or maybe it's an issue with GAS, is I can't get it to run on sites. I linked this code to a spreadsheet and it does what it's supposed to when I open it (hides every row that doesn't have my email address). However, if I link the same spreadsheet to a google site, the code does not seem to run and the windows will still show all the other rows.

Comment: The answer below isn't complete. If you put more effort (ie code thst you tried and what doesnt work with it) ill post my comments to the current answer.

Comment: Yah, i've got a bit of code now that does what I want, but with some issues. I'll edit the main post to include it.

Comment: ok i added a comment to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a web app proxy between your spreadsheet and the gadget. This technique is demonstrated (along with working code to do what you're looking for) in Romain's [Row-level permissions](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1GQkhm9mizwY-o7r4i093ASGonuRs7JPpJx4QgK2GRRw/edit#slide=id.g6f5c7fa_1_14) addendum to his [Awesome Tables](http://goo.gl/2f0bX) gadget.

Comment: Mogsdad to the rescue! Awesome, this is exactly what I wanted. Do you know if there is a way to have the gadget, once on the site, refresh the table without having to refresh the whole webpage?

Comment: Always glad to help! As it stands, no refresh - the gadget would need to support that via an AJAX-like behavior. Maybe @Romain-Vialard could add that? I gave the [URL Redirector Gadget](http://www.k8oms.net/refresh) a try, but it actually refreshes the whole page, which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, you would need to do the script 'on open' and the gadget does not fire that trigger.

You could create an apps script for the site   that 
1. gets the current active user
2. looks up the data on the spreadsheet
3. returns html for the site page

publish the script as a webapp, execute as user running app

include apps script gadget where you want the html

Comment: yes, use a webapp for this (uiapp or htmlapp). But, no need to publish as user running, publish to run as owner ("me"). that way you dont even need to give read access to the users. also simplifies authentication, assuming all users are in the same domain. else you need to execute as "user running the app" to be able to get the user email

Comment: Ok. So I know how to save the email and the cell to the right to a variable, but I'm not sure how to push that information to a box or something inside a site. I know you need to create an html file in the code project, but getting the variable to display on the site is what I'm not sure on.

Comment: Ok so I tried `<div id="score2"></div>` in an html file and put `document.getElementById("score2").innerHTML = "You have a score of " + score;` 
(I have a variable now called score that holds the value associated with the users email)
However, when I try to run this as a webapp, google says it doesn't return anything