# Display variable as html in Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Let's say we have a variable. This variable was created in google app script. On that app script project, you have two files. First, the .gs file, where the variable came from. Next, you have the html file. How do you transfer the variable to html?

```
GAS:
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
function items() {
    var exmp = 45;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "You have " + exmp + " items";    

HTML:
<script>
    google.script.run.items();
</script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

However, this doesn't work. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4):

If you read over the [Private Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions) section of the HTML service documentation, you'll find an example that does almost exactly what you're trying. The code below adapts that example to yours.

You need to keep the GAS server stuff separate from the HTML client stuff. For example, `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = ...` means nothing in the context of the server / GAS code. Instead, the modification of the `document` will be done by Javascript on the client side - in this case, by a *[success handler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers)*.

A success handler is a client-side Javascript *callback function* that will receive the asynchronous response from your server function `items()`.

> Client-side calls to server-side functions are asynchronous: after the
>   browser requests that the server run the function doSomething(), the
>   browser continues immediately to the next line of code without waiting
>   for a response.

This means that there is no waiting for the return code from the call to your server function... the browser just keeps going. You'll see this in this example, as the "More loading..." text gets displayed after the `google.script.run` call, but before the response is received.

What if `items()` needs to do something more advanced... like read info from a spreadsheet? Go ahead and change it... just make sure that you `return` the text you want displayed, and that what you're returning is going to be valid HTML (so the `innerHTML` operation is OK).

#### Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function items() {
  Utilities.sleep(5000);   // Added to allow time to see the div content change
  var exmp = 45;
  return( "You have " + exmp + " items" );    
}
```

#### index.html

```
<div id="test">Loading...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function onSuccess(items) {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = items;
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).items();

  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "More loading...";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need first to create the HTML using the createHTMLOutput function
In order for you to append strings youo have to use the var.append method

```
function items(){
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(email);
  var string1 = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>You have </p>')
  string1.append(output);
  string2= HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p> items</p>')
  string1.append(string2);
  Logger.log(string1.getContent());
}
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output)

Comment: You should really explain why this solves the problem.

Comment: @NathanielFord its pretty obvious! the user is missing a critical createHtMloutput function

Comment: Your answer (rightfully) landed in the low-quality review queue. If the correct answer is 'you are missing `createHtmlOutput()` your answer doesn't clearly indicate that, and more to the point could stand to describe the difference between `createHtmlOutput()` and `createHtmlOutputFromFile()`, or at least why one is in error. Typically speaking "Try this" and a block of non-commented code will be voted low-quality. The only reason I left the comment was so you were aware of the queue status.

Comment: I guess I should've made a better example. This works if the variable is always 45. What I really have is this: GAS checks a spreadsheet and looks for the users email address. After it finds it, it saves a value associated with it to the variable. So each time, the variable is different.

Comment: @user3743564 the key thing here is create htmloutput function.  You can adjust the rest.

Comment: @user3743564 pls ask a new question with more specific google script with how you are getting the exel email address

Comment: @user3743564 it's midnight here. (i'm in ireland) if you ask a new question i will answer it in the morning. i'm an early riser!

Comment: Oh, this is actually the second question, really. You can see the code I'm using this for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642179/view-specific-row-based-on-username-in-google-sheets) Thanks for your continuing help, though.