# Google drive app: How can i get my HTML file to read a varitable defined in code.gs?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Novice programmer here, please be gentle.

I'm attempting to create a series of search functions in an HTML file that can search the contents of a google drive database, and display the results in a popup.

Here is the relevant code:

Code.GS

```
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function load() {
data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues()
};
```

page.html

```
google.script.run.load()


function poponload() {
    testwindow = window.open("", "mywindow", 'location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=400,height=200');
    testwindow.moveTo(0, 0);
    testwindow.document.write('<br>Date = ', data[1][1]);

}
```

When the varitable 'data' is called from the html file, the javascript console is reporting that it is not defined. I have read and re-read the documentation at

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

and

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

But the answer still eludes me. What am I doing wrong? Or perhaps not doing, to get the 'data' variable to be read by the page.html file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display variable as html in Google App Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24663041/display-variable-as-html-in-google-app-script)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [the official documentation about this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

In short, call your server functions with success or failure handlers. If the function that you are calling is returning anything, then it will be passed to the callback function you specified.

**Client**

```
$(function(){ 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).load();
}); //this is jQuery lib, and the function will run when the document is ready, not when the script is loaded, which is usually a better practice
function poponload(data) {
  testwindow = window.open("", "mywindow",'location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=400,height=200');
  testwindow.moveTo(0, 0);
  testwindow.document.write('<br>Date = ', data[1][1]);
}
```

**Server**

```
function load(){
  var data;
  ...get data somehow...
  return data;
}
```